# How to deform (randomize) object so it would look different?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I have [3d tooth](https://gyazo.com/15b9a8e61adeca560b896bcf2cea468c), and I need to make it look different.
Is there any way to deform it? Scaling it, isn't what I need. My model has around 2kk faces and I have troubles editing subdivision and fractal settings.

My goal is writing a script that will randomize my tooth.

Comment: I would look at adding a Lattice as a Modifier. You can then randomise the vertices of the lattice and apply that to your tooth. The lattice can be a simple or complicated as you need,

Comment: @rob lattice doesnt let me pick my tooth as an object. Also Lattice modifier has a red color for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Lattice Object and set its resolution for your requirements. 
[image: Lattice settings]

Select your Tooth and add the Lattice Modifier, select your Lattice.
[image: Lattice applied]

You can now edit the Lattice vertices and deform the Tooth.

Feel free to add additional Lattices and have the deformations compound.

You will have to investigate how best to do all this in Python, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you please tell me how do I fill my tooth? it's hollow now, but i want it to be whole. Solidify modifier doesnt work correctly

Comment: please ask a new question with details and screen shots,

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149387/how-to-fill-a-hollow-object-to-make-it-whole-inside