# How to fill a hollow object to make it whole inside?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I have a [model of tooth](https://gyazo.com/3ebe0eb91c78814bdc174427d8bf7dc4) which is [empty inside](https://gyazo.com/54bf0596168c449a4a621d10c07176a3). I need it to be filled.
Solidify modifier doesnt work correctly. How can I fill it?

I have a camera script which makes camera slowly move forward, so it makes a result similar to DICOM files. And to achieve more realistic result I need it to be filled

Comment: please show a screenshot of the wireframe, maybe even share your file

Comment: When is the Emptiness a problem? If you use a Boolean to Cut the Tooth the Tooth will appear solid inside. The Boolean Mesh will need to be large enough to encompass all the affect vertices.

Comment: @moonboots https://gyazo.com/a8eca688cbc347874b4129947c951819

Comment: by the way, if the geometry's normal are inconsistent, or if there is ambiguity such as non convex shapes that intersect in the same mesh intersection, that wreaks havok on the boolean modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polygonal models don't have an inside. They tell a renderer where their surfaces are.

If you want to slice an object as if it were solid, you have to reconstruct a surface where the slice cuts across it.

Here we have a cube inside a sphere inside a cube. All three objects have a Boolean modifier assigned to them.

[image]

The other cube displayed in wireframe to the left is a cutter object, and will be used as a target in the Boolean modifiers, set to 'Difference'. This will cut away the objects inside its volume, an construct a surface at its intersection with them, making it look as if the objects are solid.

Actually, there are 3 separate cutter-cubes, one as a target for each modifier, with their leading faces just slightly displaced from one another. If all the objects were cut in exactly the same place, Blender wouldn't know which new cut surface was in front of which,  and there would be rendering artefacts. So the outside cube is cut away slightly more than the sphere, which is cut away slightly more than the inner cube.

Now if you animate the cutter-cubes together, you can create the illusion that the objects are solid.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To Cut into the Tooth so you can use the Boolean Modifier.

Add a Cube[image: viewport wireframe] and set to Wireframe in the Viewport

Now add a Boolean Modifier to your Tooth and select the Cube.
[image: boolean modifier]

Comment: No, that doesnt do what I want, it still empty inside, I need it to be filled

Comment: I added more details to description

Comment: Why does it need to be filled?  I don't believe blender can fill an object.

Comment: dear cxnt1, objects in 3D are always hollow! (at least as long as you use polygon modeling, voxel models are something completely different and not what Blender supports). It is simply impossible to have a "filled" object. And as long as you do not go into the model with your camera, there wont be any problem with that.

Comment: Okay, I got it @morph3us. FYI, DICOM works similar to x-ray, and what I'm doing is creating a 3d objects to make files similar to DICOM. Real tooth is filled with something, and I'm trying to achieve the same result with 3d tooth for medical purposes.

Comment: ah, okay, i see where your problem is. then you should model a seperate object for the filling, which you can give the exact same boolean modifier as the tooth itself. or you could try using a 3D noise as albedo in the tooth`s shader, maybe?

Comment: @morph3us can you post it as an answer with more details please? I can provide you with tooth model if needed

Comment: sry, i`m at work, cant help indepth. I could be totally wrong, but off the top of my head: Get a PBR Shader going, plug a noise texture into the base color and try the boolean stuff again. The new face should have a texture that changes depending on the depth you ar cutting into.

Comment: @morph3us I'm pretty new to blender and dont really know how to do it. So if you have time, could you post answer later